# git wildcard - remove all instances of a subdirectory

Tags: git, version-control, find

I am trying to execute `git rm --cached -r <folder>` to remove all instances of a folder named .svn recursively. I have tried this:

```
.svn
/.svn
/*/.svn
/*/*/.svn

etc
```

And it works, but I'm sure there is a more dynamic way.

Thanks

Comment: Just in case: Note that Git is able to nicely import a SVN repository,  preserving history.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right solution would be:

```
find . -type d -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --cached -r --
```

@gregor's will fail on the directories with spaces.

Comment: Use --ignore-unmatch on the git command if there are "did not match.." errors . . .

4 years old, but still top result in google.

Comment: For the uninitiated in `find`, you can use wildcards (`*`) in the `-name` parameter, and change `type` to `-f` (instead of `-d`) to search for files. And don't forget about `--ignore-unmatch`, as @steve76 said above.

Answer (score 3):

`find`, pipes and `xargs` are your friends:

```
find . -name .svn | xargs git rm -r
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name .svn -exec git rm -r --cached {} \;
```

There is no need for calling xargs if you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
find . -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r --
```

Thank you @steve76 for the --ignore-unmatch

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other changes in your worktree (you can stash them first), there's probably an easier way:

```
find -type d -name .svn -delete
git add -u
git commit -m 'remove svn folders -- no idea which maniac would stage them'
```

If you only want to unstage them, but not physically delete them, go with [anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617513/112968):

```
find -type d -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -r --cached
```